# How to ssh to docker container

Tags: docker, ssh

I am running the container **hypriot/rpi-busybox-httpd**

I am trying to ssh to docker container, but it is giving this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ docker exec -it cc55da85b915 bash
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH"

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ docker exec -it cc55da85b915 sh
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"sh\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: What happens if you specify the full path to `bash`, _e.g._ `docker exec -it cc55da85b915 /bin/bash` (or `/usr/local/bin/bash`, or wherever `bash` is located in that image)?

Comment: @Castaglia that should probably be an accepted answer :)

Comment: @Castaglia  @ZathrusWriter  I tried `$ docker exec -it baa50167dd75 /bin/bash` but I still got this error `rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory"`

Comment: OK, that's progress.  From the [rpi-busybox-httpd](https://github.com/hypriot/rpi-busybox-httpd) repo, it looks your image is built with the [dockerize](https://github.com/larsks/dockerize), which installs _only_ the files needed for running.  As this is the case, I suspect you will not be able to exec any kind of shell on that image.

Comment: well, I doubt, after lots of troubleshooting I tried : `docker exec -it baa50167dd75 /bin/bash` and now I get this error.
`could not read CA certificate "/home/pi/.docker/ca.pem": open /home/pi/.docker/ca.pem: no such file or directory` so that means I need CA certificate for docker. on my raspberry pi `.docker` folder is not there but on my mac it is so I have not clue from where to get the CA cert for my docker on pi that will work

Comment: If you really want to `ssh` as the question originally states, you can follow the instructions at: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2015/11/docker-workaround-lack-of-network-connectivity-between-client-and-container/

Answer (score 165, accepted):

It could be your image does not have the binary /bin/bash installed (as suggested before), I had the same problem and I was able to enter into the container using /bin/sh

```
docker exec -ti cc55da85b915 /bin/sh
```

Another workaround could be execute directly the commands without get access to any shell.

```
docker exec -ti cc55da85b915 ls /etc
```

Comment: It worked for me! Also can you tell us what are the -ti args for?

Comment: @FernandoFradegrada "-t" is for "tty", basically it tells to docker to allocate a terminal session to execute the command. "-i" is for interactive, the docker will keep listening from the standard input (keyboard) to let the user introduce more command. Here is the link to the official documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#description

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!!

Comment: I'd like to add that the same thing works for `kubectl` command when `bash` doesn't work.

Answer (score 23):

The image you're using seems that it doesn't have the binary **/bin/bash** installed but it should have **/bin/sh**

Try:

```
docker exec -it cc55da85b915 sh
```

Answer (score 3):

You might need to specify the *full* path to `bash`, *e.g.*:

```
docker exec -it cc55da85b915 /bin/bash
```

or `/usr/local/bin/bash`, or wherever bash is located in that image.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You have many different ways to do that, you can attach using docker's attach command.

```
$ sudo docker attach cc55da85b915 #by ID
```

Or you can use docker exec command:

```
$ sudo docker exec -i -t cc55da85b915 /bin/bash
```

If `/bin/bash` fails, you can use `/bin/sh` that works in more containers:

```
$ sudo docker exec -i -t cc55da85b915 /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are still looking for an answer. This worked for me on windows.

```
winpty docker exec -it <containerid> sh
```

Comment: What is `winpty` ?

Comment: Please read about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199794/winpty-and-git-bash

Answer (score 2):

Try Below Command:

```
docker exec -it cc55da85b915 /bin/busybox sh
```

To list all the available commands use:

```
docker exec -it cc55da85b915 /bin/busybox --list
```

Comment: can confirm `sh` worked for me on wsl2 (windows 11)

Answer (score 1):

For Alpine based image, docker exec -ti cc55da85b915 /bin/sh and docker exec -ti cc55da85b915 ls /etc worked. As suggested by 'Esteban Collado'.

However for other Linux versions I use,
docker exec -ti cc55da85b915 bash

Comment: This probably doesn't need to be an answer if you don't add much new information

Answer (score 0):

This will also relevant for Kubernetes pods.

For example if you'll try to connect to a pod which doesn't contain the shell you specified:

```
kubectl exec -it some-busybox-pod bash
```

(busybox have `sh` on it not `bash`).

You'll end up with the same error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
```