# Winpty and Git Bash

Tags: python, git-bash, winpty

I had the same issue as [Python not working in the command line of git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash), where in Git Bash, when I type `Python`, it just hangs.

However, typing `winpty python` works perfectly.

What exactly is `winpty`? Why is the above command useful?

Comment: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git-sdk-64/pull/35

Answer (score 54):

Quoting [the readme](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty/):

> **`winpty`** is a Windows software package providing an interface similar to a Unix `pty-master` for communicating with Windows console programs.

Winpty is a compatibility layer that allows you to run a Windows console application from a Linux terminal.

- When you cross-compile a program for Windows from Linux, the resulting binary will be a Windows console application that can be run directly from a Linux terminal without the need for `winpty`.
- However, if you build a program natively on Windows, the resulting binary will be a Windows GUI application that cannot be run from a Linux terminal.
  In order to run a Windows GUI application from a Linux terminal, you need to use `winpty`.

That is why you need it as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32599341/6309):

> The software works by starting the `winpty-agent.exe` process with a new, hidden console window, which bridges between the console API and terminal input/output escape codes. It polls the hidden console's screen buffer for changes and generates a corresponding stream of output.

[`rprichard/winpty`](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty) mentions:

> The package consists of a library (libwinpty) and a tool for Cygwin and MSYS for running Windows console programs in a Cygwin/MSYS pty.

As detailed in "[`mintty/mintty`  Tips](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/Tips#inputoutput-interaction-with-alien-programs)":

> When interacting with programs that use a native Windows API for command-line user interaction (“console mode”), a number of undesirable effects are observed; this is the [pty incompatibility problem](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/56) and the [character encoding incompatibility problem](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/376).
> This basically affects all programs not compiled in a cygwin or msys environment (and note that MinGW is not msys in this context).
>
> As a workaround, you can use `winpty` as a wrapper to invoke the Windows program.

---

So:

> Why do many tools work in plain CygWin but some of them also need winpty?

This was asked (specifically for Python) in [`msys2/MINGW-packages` issue 2645](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/2645#issuecomment-312242133)

> there's a non-zero cost associated with using winpty, and most of the time, mintty works fine anyway.
> Your problem stems from trying to use mingw python which is a native windows build, and hence expects it to be used from a windows console.
> mintty uses pipes for input/output, so it doesn't look like a proper terminal to most programs.
>
> On the other hand, if you use msys2 (or cygwin) python (.e.g  `/usr/local/bin/python2`), everything just works.

(With [`msys2/MINGW-packages` PR 2675](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/pull/2675), python3 detects the terminal correctly)

---

See also "[**Python not working in the command line of git bash**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76918262/6309)", by [Gabriel Staples](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4561887/gabriel-staples).

Comment: OK…but isn't that a description of what CygWin is for? Why do many tools work in plain CygWin but some of them also need winpty?

Comment: @EastofNowhere I suspect because it is the native Windows build version of Python. See my edited answer.

Comment: So, is this accurate if I make this statement?: If the program is cross-compiled for Windows, from Linux, it does _not_ require being called through `winpty`, but if it is built natively on Windows, it _does_ require being called through `winpty`.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Yes, that statement is accurate.

Winpty is a compatibility layer that allows you to run a Windows console application from a Linux terminal. When you cross-compile a program for Windows from Linux, the resulting binary will be a Windows console application that can be run directly from a Linux terminal without the need for winpty. However, if you build a program natively on Windows, the resulting binary will be a Windows GUI application that cannot be run from a Linux terminal. In order to run a Windows GUI application from a Linux terminal, you need to use winpty.

Comment: @VonC, thank you. I think that's a better answer than your answer. Consider making that the opening to your answer.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Thank you for your feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.