# How do I get colorized output on my windows git-bash terminal?

Tags: windows, terminal, git-bash

How do I get colorized highlighting on the output?
e.g

```
npm start  
npm test
etc.
```

[image: npm start example]

**System:**
Windows 10
Git version 2.16.1.windows.4
Node 5.6.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The terminal was a MinTTY, which does not support colors it seems. Fixed it by re-installing and ticking of Windows Terminal.

Answer (score 27):

Uninstall Git Bash for Windows 10 and run the installer again:

- Click next until you'll prompt to choose to *Configure the terminal emulator to use with Git Bash*, here you select **Use Windows default console window** (instead of the default option which use [MinTTY](https://mintty.github.io/) as terminal emulator)
- Click next and finish the installation

Test if it works correctly:

- Open Git Bash (cmd will open up), try to use `ls` you'll see all folder colored in blue
- Try some [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) by running `echo -e "\033[44m\033[37m Test \033[0m"` you'll se the text *Test* with a blue background as seen in the screenshot below

[image]

Windows 10 Console support [24-bit color](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/09/22/24-bit-color-in-the-windows-console/) and [ANSI escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences)

Answer (score 6):

For me, it was choosing **Windows default console window** instead of **MinTTY** that made color output not working.

My solution:

1. Uninstall `git bash`; during installing, choose **MinTTY** (the default option).
2. After installation, head over to `C:\Program Files\Git\etc`, open your git bash
3. `vim ~/.bashrc` (for some reason using an editor doesn't work; I guess it's a privilege issue)
4. Under `# Add colors to 'ls'` change it to
   `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`

Then restart and it should work.

My version: git version 2.24.1.windows.2

Answer (score 1):

## Use `winpty`

Windows Git Bash has some documented quirks: [Winpty and Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199794/winpty-and-git-bash)

```sh
$ winpty npm start
winpty: error: cannot start 'npm': Not found in PATH
```

Again another windows / git bash quirk, it doesn't attempt to resolve executables ending in `.cmd` so it needs a nudge.

```sh
$ winpty npm.cmd start
```

The same applies for `yarn` with:

```sh
winpty yarn.cmd start
```

While we are here and you are having trouble getting `gyp` to locate your Python2 install location to compile native extensions then try this:

```sh
env PYTHON=/c/Python27/ winpty yarn.cmd install
```

Git Bash overrides your `PYTHON` environment variable for only the duration of this command. You get `winpty` to run the pseudo-tty session to allow animation rendering and coloring.

*Assuming your python 2 install location is C:\Python27*