# command not found after reinstalling git bash with "Windows default console window"

Tags: bash, git

Before re-installing Git Bash, I was using "MinTTY as default terminal emulator". I just wanted my git bash to be colorful! Reinstall, follow this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52770624/7494877). Then when I use the same Git Bash apparently my common commands which is already installed before like:

1. nvm
2. node
3. npm
4. code

Is all gone! How do I get all of my command list back? I have `python` running thought, because I wrote in `.bashrc` `alias python= winpty python`. Are there any way to add those commands without adding them one by one through PATH environment variables? Or do I have to keep adding my list in `.bashrc`?

Thank you!

Comment: Unless you can copy your old path from somewhere, I doubt there's anything easier than adding those binaries' folders to your `$PATH` one by one

Comment: What speaks against setting up the PATH so that it contains all the directories necessary? If you don't want to do this, defining  an `alias` or better a `function` is certainly an option.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for the attention.

Apparently, I was using the first CLI that is offered by the installation launcher after the installation is done. With the same CLI, I was so confused why does this CLI doesn't run my usual commands. However, turns out it can be solved by simply closing and opening a new CLI. Then everything went fine.

I sure felt so silly. **Should've tried restarting it from the beginning.**