# How to use python on gitbash

Tags: python, windows, freeze, git-bash

Python will not run in git bash (Windows). When I type python in the command line, it takes me to a blank line without saying that it has entered python 3.9.1 like it does in Powershell. It doesn't give me an error message, but python just doesn't run.

This is what happens when I type python. It just freezes. Any Idea on how to fix it. I cannot use command prompt because it causes some error when I import a module it says ModuleNotFound.

```
Selvi@DESKTOP-H75HFL5 MINGW64 /
$ python

2*2
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199794/winpty-and-git-bash

Comment: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git-sdk-64/pull/35

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Getting python run in git bash you simply can type `winpty python` or you can use `python -i`

Note: if you use `winpty python` you can exit python with `CTRL + Z` or `exit()`, but if you used `python -i`, you only can exit with `exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was having the same problem. The only thing is that when you enter the Python command prompt with python -i, you can only exit it with quit()