# Cannot exec into container using GitBash when using Docker Compose

Tags: docker, powershell, docker-compose, git-bash

I'm new to Docker Compose, but have used Docker for years. The screen shot below is of PowerShell and of GitBash. If I run containers without docker-compose I can `docker exec -it <container_ref> /bin/bash` with no problems from either of these shells.
However, when running using `docker-compose up` both shells give no error when attempting to use `docker-compose exec`. They both just hang a few seconds and return to prompt.
Lastly, for some reason I do get an error in GitBash when using what I know: `docker exec...`. I've used this for years so I'm perplexed and posting a question. What does Docker Compose do that messes with GitBash docker ability, but not with PowerShell? And, why the hang when using `docker-compose exec...`, but no error?
[image: can exec using powershell but not gitbash]

I am using `tty: true` in the docker-compose.yml, but that honestly doesn't seem to make a difference. Not to throw a bunch of questions in one post, but whatever is going on could it also be the reason I can't hit my web server in the browser only when using Docker Compose to run it?

````
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  pgdata:
     external: true   

services:
    db:
        image: postgres
        container_name: trac-db
        tty: true
        restart: 'unless-stopped'
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_DB: iol
        volumes:
            - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        network_mode: 'host'
        expose:
            - 5432
    web:
        image: lindben/trac-server
        container_name: trac-server
        tty: true
        restart: 'unless-stopped'
        environment:
            ADDRESS: localhost
            PORT: 3000
            NODE_ENV: development
        depends_on:
            - db
        network_mode: 'host'
        privileged: true
        expose:
            - 1234
            - 3000
    ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue explanation

I'm going to be assuming you're using [Docker for Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/) and so the reason you can `docker exec` just fine using PowerShell is because both PS and Docker for Desktop built for windows while GitBash which is based on **bash** which isn't natively used in Windows but in Linux and is based on the Linux shell ([bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) =  Bourne-Again SHell).

### Basic Solution

So when using a windows program that needs a tty you need some sort of "adapter", like `winpty` for example, to bridge the gap between Docker for Desktop native interface and GitBash's (or Bash's) one.

Here's a more detailed explanation on [winpty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199794/winpty-and-git-bash)

### Better Solution - specific

putting all of this aside, if trying only to use the compose options it maybe better for you to advise [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249744/interactive-shell-using-docker-compose)

### Subsequent Hangup Issue

Now, regarding your web service issue, I think that you're not actually publicly exposing your application using the expose tag. take a look at the docker-compose
[expose reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#expose). what you need is to add a "ports" tag like so as referenced [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports):

```
db:
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
web:
    ports:
      - "1234:1234"
      - "3000:3000"
```

I hope this solves your pickle ;)

Comment: Thank you for the info. I cannot use ports and use `network: host`. I need to use `network: host` to send email because just mapping port 25:25 doesn't work on my remote dev machine as IT only has the host white listed.
BTW, is there maybe a way to tell Docker for Desktop to use GitBash instead? It seems fairly inflexible in that way. I actually do `docker-compose up` in a VSCode GitBash Integrated Terminal.

Comment: I guess you technically did answer my question, but if anybody else has a way to tell Docker Desktop to use GitBash that'd be wonderful!